# “Limit Exceeded: Email body size” when sending htmlBody

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using this google script to send excell sheet in mail without changing its format but when the file is large it shows Limit Exceeded: Email Body Size.

````
// Refer to this link for installation: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter
function convSheetAndEmail(rng, email, subj)
{
  var HTML = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng);
//  Logger.log("theSheetContents: " + HTML);
//  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subj, '', {htmlBody : HTML});
  MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: email,
     subject: subj,
     htmlBody: HTML});
}
function doGet()
{
  // or Specify a range like A1:D12, etc.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  Logger.log("theSheetContents: " + dataRange);
  var emailUser = '***@.com';
  var subject = 'PSR';
  convSheetAndEmail(dataRange, emailUser, subject);
}```
````

Comment: This seems a reasonable error message.  Why do you think that this should not happen some of the time?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your `htmlBody` generated from the spreadsheet is too large. You may consider selecting a smaller range in the spreadsheet or covert the range to a PDF/XLS file and attach it to the email instead of sending it inline.

Comment: when i copy the data from excel sheet and send it, mail successfully sends

Answer (score 0):

At [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) you can see the [Current limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), which vary depending if you have a G Suite account or not and the kind of G Suite account that you possess.

---

#### Notice

the difference between the ***email body size***:

> Email body size   200kB / msg 200kB / msg 400kB / msg 400kB / msg 400kB
> / msg

And the ***email total attachments size***:

> Email total attachments size  25MB / msg  25MB / msg  25MB / msg  25MB /
> msg   25MB / msg

---

As you can see, there is a huge difference in the size of your ***email body size*** and the ***files size*** that you could attach.